# Tab built and uploaded from eclips doesnt show up

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, apex

I've uploaded an open source project I found on github to my sandbox. This package includes tabs, and they are showing up under Create -> Tabs -> Visualforce Tabs. But I can not make them appear in any other menu anywhere on the site. Not to mention the All tabs (+) button..
I've looked for permissions or anything else that would seem logical, but I'm the SA and should be able to see everything. Anyone have any ideas? Im totally clueless atm

Comment: By the way you can ask Salesforce questions directly on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your profile and scroll down to where that tab is listed -- it may be set as "Tab Hidden," in which case you'll want to change that so that it's shown for you.  Even the system admin profile can have tabs hidden.